# Related to UIPickerView in IOS

Tags: ios

I created a pickerview and i returned a view to that. But my selection indicator selects half of the view only. So, I want to increase the height for selection indicator to select entire view without using any transparent image. Is it possible? If Yes, please help me to come out from this...

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code:

```
pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
pickerView.delegate = self;
pickerView.dataSource = self;
[pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

view.inputView = pickerView;
```

And if you want to hide selection Indicator then use following code;

```
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = NO;
```